# How many sides and what are the probabilities of each side for an unfair die?

Tags: probability, bayesian

## Problem

I would like to run an inference that predicts from a series of die rolls, how many sides the die has, and what is the probability of landing on each side.

## Example

For example, imagine a die has a finite $N$ number of sides with arbitrary labels with corresponding probabilities $P=\{p_1,...,p_N\}$ which are not necessarily equal. For a limited number of rolls, you would only be able to see $M\leq N$ number of sides with corresponding occurrences $Y=\{y_1,...,y_M\}$. The goal is to then to infer $N$ and $P$ from the observation.

## Initial thoughts

My first guess was to model the observations with a multinomial distribution using an MCMC calculate the posterior on both $N$ and $P$, putting a prior on $N$ following part II of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169697/how-many-sides-does-a-die-have-bayesian-inference-in-jags). It's not particularly clear to me how to then measure $P$ using an MCMC (or alternative method) as the number of parameters changes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you consider only physically-realistic dice? Because it wouldn’t be possible to create a fair die of an arbitrary number of sides, there are some constraints.

Comment: Yes, so the number of sides would be finite.

Comment: @astroH I think what Tim says is about the geometric structure of the die, e.g. does a 7-face polyhedra exist physically?

Comment: I think the key thing here is that it doesn't have to be fair, or a die even.

Comment: @gunes Yes, 7 face polyhedra certainly exist. e,g, take a cube and cut a corner (vertex) off, adding a face (and also two vertices and three edges). Clearly polyhedra with any number of faces greater than 3 are possible, though dice of fewer than 4 faces also exist (e.g. long dice) and polyhedra where more than one face carry the same number (like a six-sided die numbered 1-3 twice)

Comment: While not needed for the question, there are many kinds of dice that are fair by symmetry - not just the Platonic solids; there are [Archimedean duals](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedeanDual.html) like the rhombic dodecahedron and the rhombic triacontahedron (30-sided), there are trapezohedra (aside from the cube, the best known being a 10-sided die) and bipyramids (aside from the octahedron, perhaps the best known is a 16-sided die).

Comment: this paper might be quite useful   Efron, B., & Thisted, R. (1976). Estimating the Number of Unsen Species: How Many Words Did Shakespeare Know? Biometrika, 63(3), 435. doi:10.2307/2335721